# How to get streaming tweets using twitter-api in clojure?

Tags: twitter, clojure

I am new to clojure. I am trying to get the streaming tweets through clojure. I'm using twitter-api library to get the streaming tweets and the code snippet is the following.

```
(ns hello-twitter
  (:use
   [twitter.oauth]
   [twitter.callbacks]
   [twitter.callbacks.handlers]
   [twitter.api.streaming])
  (:require
   [clojure.data.json :as json]
   [http.async.client :as ac])
  (:import
   (twitter.callbacks.protocols AsyncStreamingCallback)))

(def my-creds (make-oauth-creds "app consumer key"
                                "app consumer secret"
                                "user-access-token"
                                "user-access-token-secret"))

(def ^:dynamic
  *custom-streaming-callback*
     (AsyncStreamingCallback. (comp println #(:text %) json/read-json #(str %2))
                      (comp println response-return-everything)
                  exception-print))

(statuses-filter :params {:track "Cricket"}
         :oauth-creds my-creds
         :callbacks *custom-streaming-callback*)
```

The :body part in returned json is supposed to be continually updated. I am getting value of :body is like `<core$promise$reify__6363@32cdfb83: :pending>` and I am unable to figure out how to get the tweets.

How to establish the uninterrupted connection to get the streaming tweets as output?

Answer (score 0):

This value is a [promise](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/promise). Instead of blocking the thread at the point of sending a request over the web, a promise was created and returned back to you so your program can continue execution. The promise later needs to be dereferenced with `deref` or `@` to get the value out.

Example copied from the linked documentation:

```
;; Create a promise
user> (def p (promise))
#'user/p ; p is our promise

;; Check if was delivered/realized
user> (realized? p)
false ; No yet

;; Delivering the promise
user> (deliver p 42)
#<core$promise$reify__5727@47122d: 42>

;; Check again if it was delivered
user> (realized? p)
true ; Yes!

;; Deref to see what has been delivered
user> @p
42

;; Note that @ is shorthand for deref
user> (deref p)
42
```

Comment: Promise is returned back. I'm not able to get the tweets only by dereferencing the promise. So, how to deliver the promise so that I can get the streaming tweets?

Comment: Sorry, I see now. I suppose if this is an infinite stream then the promise will never have a final delivered value. Perhaps you need to use `doseq` on the dereferenced promise to perform a side effect as each tweet occurs?